# PHP: Return count of some values in multidimensional array but retain other values i.e id

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array that is really large and varying but structured like this:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array 
      'id' => string '6' 
      'name' => string 'Adams Clasp' 
  1 => 
    array 
      'id' => int 185
      'name' => string 'Acrylic'
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '268' 
      'name' => string 'Adams Clasp (Splints)' 
  3 => 
    array 
      'id' => int 11
      'name' => string 'Arrow Clasp'
  4 => 
    array 
      'id' => int 11
      'name' => string 'Arrow Clasp' 
  5 => 
    array 
      'id' => string '0' 
      'name' => string 'Labial Bow' 
  6 => 
    array 
      'id' => string '6' 
      'name' => string 'Adams Clasp' 
  7 => 
    array 
      'id' => string '6' 
      'name' => string 'Adams Clasp'
```

I would like to get output that is similar to as if `array_count_values()` were called on the array if it were not multidimensional/ just keys and `name` except retaining the associated `'id'` as a value and remain multidimensional. In this example output should look like:

```
array 
  'Adams Clasp' => 
       array 
         'id' => string '6' 
         'count' => int 3
  'Acrylic' => 
       array 
         'id' => int 185
         'count' => int 1
  'Adams Clasp (Splints)' => 
       array
         'id' => string '268' 
         'count => int 1
  'Arrow Clasp' => 
       array 
         'id' => int 11
         'count' => int 2
  'Labial Bow' => 
       array 
         'id' => string '0' 
         'count' => int 1
```

Am running `php5.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly constructed foreach loop will do the trick.  When a name is first found, set it as a key, and declare a default subarray for it (`id` and `count` = `0`).  Then just increment the count value for every occurrence.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/390ab1f36c5285482402747beafb3523e0300bc9))

```
$array=[ 
    ['id'=>'6','name'=>'Adams Clasp'],
    ['id'=>185,'name'=>'Acrylic'],
    ['id'=>'268','name'=>'Adams Clasp (Splints)'],
    ['id'=>11,'name'=>'Arrow Clasp'],
    ['id'=>11,'name'=>'Arrow Clasp'],
    ['id'=>'0','name'=>'Labial Bow'],
    ['id'=>'6','name'=>'Adams Clasp'],
    ['id'=>'6','name'=>'Adams Clasp']
];

foreach($array as $a){
    if(!isset($result[$a['name']])){
        $result[$a['name']]=['id'=>$a['id'],'count'=>0];
    }
    ++$result[$a['name']]['count'];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Adams Clasp' => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
    'count' => 3,
  ),
  'Acrylic' => 
  array (
    'id' => 185,
    'count' => 1,
  ),
  'Adams Clasp (Splints)' => 
  array (
    'id' => '268',
    'count' => 1,
  ),
  'Arrow Clasp' => 
  array (
    'id' => 11,
    'count' => 2,
  ),
  'Labial Bow' => 
  array (
    'id' => '0',
    'count' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Variant uses arrays functions :

```
$array = [
    ['id' => '6','name' => 'Adams Clasp'],
    ['id' => 185,'name' => 'Acrylic'],
    ['id' => '268','name' => 'Adams Clasp (Splints)'],
    ['id' => 11,'name' => 'Arrow Clasp'],
    ['id' => 11,'name' => 'Arrow Clasp'],
    ['id' => '0','name' => 'Labial Bow'],
    ['id' => '6','name' => 'Adams Clasp'],
    ['id' => '6','name' => 'Adams Clasp'],

];
$ids = array_column($array , 'name' , 'id');

array_map(function($count , $id , $name)use(&$out){
    $out[$name] = ['id' =>  $id, 'count' => $count];
} , array_count_values(array_column($array , 'name')) , array_keys($ids),array_values($ids));

print_r($out);
```